# Ivy, JavaScript deps, or using jarred javascript

Tags: javascript, ivy

I have started using Ivy to manage my dependencies, and now i want to resolve things like jQuery and other common JavaScript libraries using Ivy.

However, the best I can get for, say, jQuery is a jar containing a number of folders, and the two variants of jQuery (normal and minimized).

What is the best option in my case? Is it possible to fetch just the jquery.min.js using Ivy? Or should I add a number of targets to unpack the fetched jars and use just the files I need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest solution is to use ivy's [url resolver](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/resolver/url.html) to retrieve the javascript files directly (See example below).

A more complete (and complex) solution is to use [packager resolver](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/resolver/packager.html) or setup a repository to host the files you need.

## Example

```
├── build.xml
├── ivysettings.xml
├── ivy.xml
└── build
    └── js
        ├── jquery.js
        ├── jquery-min.js
        ├── jquery-migrate.js
        └── jquery-migrate-min.js
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="build" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

    <target name="resolve">
        <ivy:resolve/>
    </target>

    <target name="build" depends="resolve">
        <ivy:retrieve pattern="build/js/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]" conf="javascript"/>
    </target>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="build"/>
    </target>

    <target name="clean-all" depends="clean">
        <ivy:cleancache/>
    </target>

</project>
```

Notes:

- The ivy retrieve task uses a configuration. This enables you to place artifacts in different locations within your build.

### ivy.xml

```
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:e="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/extra">
    <info organisation="com.myspotontheweb" module="demo"/>

    <configurations>
        <conf name="javascript" description="JS dependencies"/>
    </configurations>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="com.jquery" name="jquery" rev="1.9.1" conf="javascript->default">
            <artifact name="jquery" type="js"/>
            <artifact name="jquery" type="js" e:classifier="min"/>
        </dependency>

        <dependency org="com.jquery" name="jquery-migrate" rev="1.1.1" conf="javascript->default">
            <artifact name="jquery-migrate" type="js"/>
            <artifact name="jquery-migrate" type="js" e:classifier="min"/>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</ivy-module>
```

Notes:

- The remote modules do not have ivy files. This forces you to specify the artifacts to be retrieved.
- This example uses a [extra attributes](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.1.0/concept.html#extra) to indicate the minified files.
- Javascript dependencies are mapped to the "javascript" configuration (See use of "retrieve" tasks in build file).

### ivysettings.xml

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="central"/>
    <resolvers>
        <ibiblio name="central" m2compatible="true"/>
        <url name="jquery">
            <artifact pattern="http://code.jquery.com/[artifact]-[revision](.[classifier]).[ext]"/>
        </url>
    </resolvers>
    <modules>
        <module organisation="com.jquery" resolver="jquery"/>
    </modules>
</ivysettings>
```

Notes:

- Default repository is Maven Central. The jquery module is mapped to it's matching url resolver.
- The optional [extra attribute](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.1.0/concept.html#extra) is used in the URL